# uploading web generated image in require.js module

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, requirejs

I am using a web labeling tool to generate image from the website, however I want to modify the function so that when I am done with labeling, instead of downloading the image to local, I want it to be uploaded into server. The function is in a javascript file and all the upload associated with JS has to do with submitting forms. There is no form and super globals, how am I supposed to upload a web generated image to server?

here is the code I currently have, it is not in html file, it is in js file.

```
var file_data = annotator.export();
var formData = dataURItoBlob(file_data);
var fd = new FormData(document);
fd.append("resultImage",formData);
url="upload/";
http.open("POST", url, true);

// headers
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-     urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", fd.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
    alert(http.responseText);
 }
}

http.send(fd);
```

php file

```
<?php
$upload_dir = "upload/";
$img = $_POST['hidden_data'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = $upload_dir . mktime() . ".png";
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
?>
```

Really appreciate your help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dataURItoBlob(file_data);` by the name of the function it looks like that is going to be returning a blob object. blob/file objects when uploaded to a php script are going to be in the `$_FILES` global, not `$_POST`. And you would use [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to move it to your desired destination.

Also you seem to be using the wrong index. You are using `hidden_data` in your php but you set the name to `resultImage` in your javascript. You would need to use the same name in php as you did in the javascript.

So your php code should look something like

```
$upload_dir = "upload/";
$img = $_FILES['resultImage'];
if($img["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
   //should do other sanitation like making sure the file 
   //that is uploaded is the actual type of file you expect
   $path = $upload_dir . mktime() . ".png";
   move_uploaded_file($img["tmp_name"], $path);   
}
```

As a side note, when using and FormData object you do not need to set the request headers like `Content-Type` as they will automatically be set by the api.

Comment: thank you Evans, sorry I don't have enough reputation to upvote yet.